# Read Last Missed Call info on Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can a native iphone app read who was the last missed caller on the call list? What about last called or last received call?

Ali

Comment: That would raise huge privacy concerns, I would be amazed if that information was available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That info is not available via published APIs.

Answer (score 1):

On the iOS 4,there is a readable directory which can read the call history.
/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db

Comment: Is this a published API? Or will using this get you rejected from the App Store?